# Phaser 3: change size of a scene without affecting the larger scene beneath it

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I currently have 2 active scenes with the smaller one on top of the larger one, but I can't seem to change the size of the smaller scene without also affecting the size of the larger scene. I have already tried the following:

```
scene.scale.setGameSize(width, height);
scene.scale.resize(width, height);
game.scale.resize(width, height);
```

When the smaller scene is used, I would put the larger scene to sleep (because I need the larger scene to still render images) then launch the smaller scene.